# How do I implement my own authentication in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to follow the authentication tutorial* for Yii2 but due to the project's requirements I need to build custom authentication. Although the tutorial does state you can make your own it doesn't elaborate on how. What files do I need to create and where and what values do I need to add to $behaviors['authenticator'] to refer to my custom auth module?

*https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-authentication.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is too broad in current state, but I will try to provide the basic algorithm.

Create class extending from `yii\filters\auth\AuthMethod`.

Where to place it it's up to you (because of using namespaces), you can follow your own convention. Let's say we place it in `common\components` folder.

You must at least implement `authenticate` method of `AuthInterface` (`challenge` and `handleFailure` already have default implementations, but you can obviously override them too).

```
namespace common\components;

use yii\filters\auth\AuthMethod;

class CustomAuth extends AuthMethod
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function authenticate($user, $request, $response)
    {
        // Put your logic here
    }
}
```

Usage in REST controller:

```
use common\components\CustomAuth;

...

 /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CustomAuth::className(),            
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

Also see how built-in auth methods are implemented (`HttpBasicAuth`, `HttpBearerAuth`, `QueryParamAuth`).

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. One follow up question though. I see you don't return boolean here. Should I throw a 401 exception when authentication fails?

Comment: Glad to help. You can upvote and accept the answer in this case.

Comment: @Dubby In case of fail use `$this->handleFailure($response);` inside of `authenticate()` method. Default implementation is: `throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('You are requesting with an invalid credential.');`. You can always override it to fit your needs, but I guess it's more common and widespread approach.